# "Given", past participle or preposition?

Tags: prepositions, past-participles, parts-of-speech

> **Given arms and hands**, a computer can do more varied physical work.

Is the word "given" in the sentence, the past participle or the preposition? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to see "given arms and hands" as a shortened if-clause with drop of "if". Subordinate clauses can be shortened by means of participle constructions.

To my surprise I find it is not easy to show that "given" is no preposition. Perhaps someone has an idea to solve this problem. Normally a connection of preposition + noun has not the sense of a when/if-clause.

Added: The full subclause would be: "If a computer is given arms and hands ... "

Answer (score 1):

> **Given** *arms and hands*, a computer can do more varied physical work.

That **given** in the quoted sentence is a past participle of verb.

Here **given** *arms and hands* is predicated upon the following noun phrase (NP) - *a computer*.

And so **given** here is nothing but a past participle of a verb.